# Drupal Views Filter for Slideshow

Tags: 7, theming, views

I have created a content type for slide show name as slider in which i have 3 fields

Image, Image Description, and Image Postion(left or right). 
I added multiple images and text for this.

Now i want to show slide show according to postion set of each image.

if image is left then it shows to left and text shows to right. and vice versa.

Anybody have idea how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much a Views theming task.  Hopefully you are familiar with either Firebug or Web Inspector for Chrome. Your "`Image Postion Right`" and "`Image Postion Left`" will have their own respective div classes so you can leverage / theme those CSS classes to get the image in the correct postion.

If you need something more powerful beyond this, you may also need to create a Custom Views Template. (In your View, you should see a link for "`Theme:Information`" -- it might be under "`Advanced`" if you are using Views 3 for Drupal 7.) Clicking on this will give you template suggestions. You may also need to use the Devel module's "[Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer)" to quickly find the field variable names.-- [see this](http://drupal.org/node/209561)

You also did not say which version of Drupal you are using so there may be some specific things relative to your Drupal version that you will need to be aware of.

So basically as you can see there are multiple ways to do what you need but this should be a good overview and resource. Theming a View is an artform and can take a while to get the hang of but once you do, it's pretty cool.